# Puppeteer - Cannot Type Input Field or Click Button

Tags: button, types, puppeteer, selector

I'm using puppeteer to automate the entry of a form. I am able to fill all fields except the email field and also cannot click subscribe button at the end of the form. Below is my code. FNAME works but #mce-EMAIL does not work (even when I try page.type). Also for some reason the selector for the subscribe button cannot be found. Below is also a screenshot of the portion of the DOM that is related to this code.

Any reason why my code may not work?

```
  await page.$eval('#mce-EMAIL', el => el.value = 'test@example.com');
  await delay(500);
  await page.type('input[name="FNAME"]', MyData[row].fname)
  await delay(500);


  await page.click('#mc-embedded-subscribe')
```

[image: DOM]

Comment: Do you have a link to the page? Maybe it's an iframe and/or checking for bots?

Comment: It’s don’t think it’s an iframe because the other inputs worked fine. The link to the page is https://www.deadstock.ca/pages/raffle.

Answer (score 1):

The problem with these kind of website is, it have same ID for multiple elements. A bad design decision.

[image]

You need to use the correct selector. Otherwise it is still filling up a hidden form.

Here is the correct selector based on the link you provided.

```
#mc_embed_signup_scroll #mce-EMAIL
```

Comment: ok i was able to type in the email field but i cannot click the button

Comment: I am pretty sure you need to study more about the selectors. There are multiple elements with same selectors, so you need to be more specific. Like instead of #mc-embedded-subscribe, you might want to use `#mc_embed_signup_scroll #mc-embedded-subscribe` and so on.